# Python plot of force in Lennard-Jones system gives TypeError

Tags: python, matplotlib, typeerror

I am trying to plot the force on the ith particle as function of its distance from the jth particle (ie. `xi-xj`) in a Lennard-Jones system. The force is given by

[image]

where sigma and epsilon are two parameters, Xi is a known quantity and Xj is variable. *The force directs from the ith particle to the jth particle*.

The code that I have written for this is given below.

```
from pylab import*
from numpy import*

#~~~ ARGON VALUES ~~~~~~~~(in natural units)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
epsilon=0.0122      # depth of potential well
sigma=0.335         # dist of closest approach
xi=0.00
xj=linspace(0.1,1.0,300)

f = 48.0*epsilon*( ((sigma**12.0)/((xi-xj)**13.0)) - ((sigma**6.0)/2.0/((xi-xj)**7.0)) ) * float(xj-xi)/abs(xi-xj)

plot(xj,f,label='force')
legend()
show()
```

But it gives me this following error.

```
f = 48.0*epsilon*( ((sigma**12.0)/((xi-xj)**11.0)) - ((sigma**6.0)/2.0/((xi-xj)**5.0)) ) * float(xj-xi)/abs(xi-xj)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Can someone help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is with the float term. But the fix isn't clear because the term doesn't make sense: 1) the term isn't in your equation; 2) you must know xi and xj are already floats since you created them on the previous line; so, what are you trying to do? Also, that looks like it's just a `sign` function.  If that's what you want, you should just use, `numpy.sign(xj-xi)`.

Comment: Yes @tom10 its only a sign function to incorporate the direction of the force. But I didn't know about this `numpy.sign` function. Thank you for your advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the term `float(xj-xi)/abs(xi-xj)` you should use

```
sign(xj-xi)
```

---

If you really want to do the division, since `xi` and `xj` are already floats you could just do:

```
(xj-xi)/abs(xi-xj)
```

More generally, if you need to convert a numpy array of ints to floats you could use either of:

```
1.0*(xj-xi)
(xj-xi).astype(float)
```

Even more generally, it's helpful in debugging to not use equations that stretch across the page because with smaller terms you can identify the location of the errors more easily.  It also often runs faster.  For example, here you calculate `xi-xj` four times, when really it only needs to be done once.  And it would be easier to read:

```
x = xi -xj

f = 48*epsilon*(s**12/x**13 - s**6/2/x**7)
f *= sign(-x)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is with this part of the expression:

```
float(xj-xi)
```

Look at the answer to a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687581/typeerror-only-length-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars-while-trying?answertab=votes#tab-top). It appears to be conflict between Python built-in functions and Numpy functions.

If you take out the 'float' it at least returns. Does it give the correct numbers?

```
f = 48.0*epsilon*( ((sigma**12.0)/((xi-xj)**11.0)) - ((sigma**6.0)/2.0/((xi-xj)**5.0)) ) * (xj-xi)/abs(xi-xj)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TypeError` is due to `float(xi-xj)`. `float()` cannot convert an iterable to a single scalar value. Instead, iterate over `xj` and convert each value in `xi-xj` to `float`. This can be easily done with

```
x = [float(j - xi) for j in xj)]
```