# Python Error only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to python coding
and i am writing a code to calculate the sum of a series, i started by writing a function where the input is the number of iterations of the sum, but when i compile it gives me the error in the line under `def G(i)` : only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Can you help me please

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.special as sp
import pylab as pylab

def G(i):
    return (sum(((-1*(2*l+1))/(4*np.pi*(l**2+l)))*sp.legendre(l)(0.5)  for l in i))

pylab.ylim([-1,1])
sumrange = np.arange(1,70,1)
plt.plot(sumrange,G(sumrange),color='red')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars while trying to exponentially fit data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687581/typeerror-only-length-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars-while-trying)

Comment: Short version: use `np.sum` instead of `sum`.

Comment: @aryamccarthy np.sum does not work, the problem is with the range inputs i think

Comment: What do you mean, 'does not work'? What's the error?

Comment: @aryamccarthy The same error as above, only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: Copying your code in to python, changing to np.sum, it works fine on G(1), but that's because it doesn't execute the sum.  Any value >1, it fails on `cosgamma undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from the fact that `i` is a sequence, not a single value. In your case, it's `np.arange(1,70,1)`.

This doesn't make sense when you call `range(1,i,1)`: `i` is not a single value. You can fix it by replacing `for l in range(1,i,1)` with `for l in i`.

There are some other problems, too—I'm not sure where `cosgamma` is defined. You should in the future provide a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, i forgot to tell that i replace cosgamma with any value i want, however for l in i is not working, it says: invalid syntax

Comment: Be sure that you removed the right number of closing parentheses when you switched it: exactly 1.

Comment: But this is till not working ( Invalid Syntax), are you sure that for l in range(1,i,1) is the same as for l in i ?

Comment: It's exactly the point that they are different constructs, otherwise you'd still get the other error. Edit your post to include the latest version of your code.