# Error: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python

```
def answer_six():
    census_df = pd.read_csv('census.csv')
    copy = census_df.copy()
    
    states = copy['STNAME'].unique()
    counties = copy['CTYNAME']
      
    play = copy.copy()

    play = play.set_index(['STNAME','CTYNAME'])
    copy = copy.set_index(['STNAME'])

    def population_with_top3 (state):        
        counties = copy.loc[state]['CTYNAME'].values        
        population_array = list(map(lambda county:int(play.loc[state,county]['CENSUS2010POP'].values),counties))        
        population_array.sort(reverse = True)        
        population = population_array[1] + population_array[2] + population_array[3]            
        return {'STNAME': state, 'POP': population}

    states_with_pop = list(map(population_with_top3,states))              
    return states_with_pop

answer_six()
```

when running the code I get:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Does anybody have any experience with this kind of issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the full error message.

Comment: @jhzv `play.loc[state,county]['CENSUS2010POP'].values` is it a single number? then only `int()` works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Error only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43945729/python-error-only-length-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens when you try to use an array in place of single value.
I think the error is in this part of your code.

```
int(play.loc[state,county]['CENSUS2010POP'].values)
```

int takes only a single value for typecasting and .values returns an array. But if the array is of size one int will ignore that its an array and take the 1st element. In you case i think your play.loc[,][''].values is returning more than one value. This happens if there is more than one row with same state name, same county name and same CENSUS2010POP.