# scipy curve_fit with arrays TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I am trying to create the curve fit with scipy for the energy eigenvalues calculated from a 4x4 Hamiltonian matrix. In the following error "energies" corresponds to the function in which I define the Hamiltonian, "xdata" is an array given after and out of the function and corresponds to k and "e" is the energy eigenvalues that a get.
The error seems to be at the Hamiltonian matrix. However if I run the code without the curve_fit everything works fine.
I have also tried using np.array according to other questions I found here but again it doesn't work.
If a give a specific xdata in the curve fit, like xdata[0], the code works but it doesn't help me much since I want the fit using all values.
Does anyone know what is the problem? Thank you all in advance!

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "fitest.py", line 70, in <module>
     popt, pcov = curve_fit(energies,xdata, e)#,
  File "/eb/software/Python/2.7.12-intel-2016b/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 651, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, args=args, full_output=1, **kwargs)
  File "/eb/software/Python/2.7.12-intel-2016b/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 377, in leastsq
    shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
  File "/eb/software/Python/2.7.12-intel-2016b/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 26, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
  File "/eb/software/Python/2.7.12-intel-2016b/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 453, in _general_function
    return function(xdata, *params) - ydata
  File "fitest.py", line 23, in energies
    [         0.0,              0.0,                      0.0,     ep-2*V4*cos(kpt*d) ]],dtype=complex)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

---

Code:

```
from numpy import sin, cos, array

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

from numpy import *

from numpy.linalg import *


def energies(kpt, a=1.0, b=2.0, c=3.0, f=4.0):

   e1=-15.0
   e2=-10.0

   d=1.0
   v0=(-2.0/d**2) 
   V1=a*v0
   V2=b*v0
   V3=c*v0
   V4=d*v0

   basis=('|S, s>', '|S,px>', '|S, py>', '|S,pz>')
   h=array([[ e1-2*V1*cos(kpt*d), -2*V2*1j*sin(kpt*d),   0.0,                   0.0 ], 
     [    2*V2*1j*sin(kpt*d), e2-2*V3*cos(kpt*d),       0.0,                        0.0],  
    [         0.0,              0.0,           e2-2*V4*cos(kpt*d),                 0.0],            
   [         0.0,              0.0,                      0.0,     e2-2*V4*cos(kpt*d) ]],dtype=complex) 

   e,psi=eigh(h)


   return e

print energies(kpt=0.0)
k2=0.4*2*pi/2.05
print energies(kpt=k2)


xdata = array([0.0,k2])
print xdata

popt, pcov = curve_fit(energies, xdata, e)


print " "
print popt
print " "
```

Comment: How are we supposed to know, what is wrong with your code, when you don't show it? You should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The most likely reason for this error message would be that your fit function uses the [math module instead of a numpy functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21697288/8881141)

Comment: Excuse me but this is the first time that I post something and I didn't know if the information given would suffice.I have added the code. The values here are random

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with your fit, you run into the same problem, if you perform

```
print energies(xdata)
```

The reason for this error message is that you put an array `kpt` into `h` as an array element and then tell numpy, to transform this array `kpt` into a complex number. Numpy is kind enough to transform an array of length one into a scalar, which then can be transformed into a complex number. This explains, why you didn't get an error message with `xdata[0]`. You can easily reproduce your problem like this

```
import numpy as np
#all fine with an array of length one
xa = np.asarray([1])
a = np.asarray([[xa, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
print a
print a.astype(complex)

#can't apply dtype = complex to an array with two elements
xb = np.asarray([1, 2])
b = np.asarray([[xb, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
print b
print b.astype(complex)
```

Idk, what you were trying to achieve with your energies function, so I can only speculate, what you were aiming at, when constructing the `h` array. Maybe a 3D array like this?

```
kpt = np.asarray([1, 2, 3])

h = np.zeros(16 * len(kpt), dtype = complex).reshape(len(kpt), 4, 4)
h[:, 0, 0] = 2 * kpt + 1
h[:, 0, 1] = kpt ** 2
h[:, 3, 2] = np.sin(kpt)
print h
```

Comment: Dear Piinthesky, thank you for your answer.I tried what you proposed but it didn't fix the problem. So I looked it up a bit more and the code worked when I used the numpy.linalg.norm for the kpt.

Comment: Good to hear. If you found a solution to your problem, it is encouraged to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).