# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I try to run this code my python says only size-1 arrays can be converted to python scalars.

Now are my inputs: `deltaDEC1`, `deltaRA1` and `Data_match['DEC_1']` all arrays 1 row and 1 column. And I want to get an array out of it with 1 row and 1 column.

```
r1 = math.sqrt(((deltaDEC1)**2)+((deltaRA1)**2)*((math.cos(Data_match['DEC_1']))**2))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-535-95d3dd661960> in <module>()

----> 1 r1 = math.sqrt(((deltaDEC1)**2)+((deltaRA1)**2)*((math.cos(Data_match['DEC_1']))**2))

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I am new to python so I don't know how I can fix this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars while trying to exponentially fit data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687581/typeerror-only-length-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars-while-trying)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can't do these operations with your data structure, but Python tries to do as much of the operation as possible (due to duck typing). See these in-depth answer: [TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars while trying to exponentially fit data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687581/typeerror-only-length-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars-while-trying)

It's also useful to test each part of the code one by one to see what's wrong, ie each parenthesized part, to see where the error arises.