# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to python scalars while calculating mean, diff, and log

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I am currently translating matlab code to python using pandas, numpy and scipy. I am not extremely knowlegable about matlab, and I have not taken a linear algebra or differential equations course so this has proved challenging. When performing some calculations, python throws a "TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python Scalars" error.

I have tried a pretty direct translation of the matlab to python using a reference sheet for matlab -> numpy functions

Below are the lines in matlab, and my python translation

matlab:

```
handles.delta = mean(diff(log(1./handles.freq)));
```

Python:

```
self.delta = np.mean(np.diff(math.log(1/self.Frequency)))
```

I expect that these lines should do the same thing, and in python self.Frequency is a 1 dimensional nparray, and all of the functions should return arrays, but python throws the error

Comment: *" self.Frequency is a 1 dimensional nparray"*  `math.log` does not accept one-dimensional numpy arrays if the length of the array is more than 1.  Try using `np.log`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars while trying to exponentially fit data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687581/typeerror-only-length-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars-while-trying)